# Big exception handler or lots of try...except clauses

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a question which is about code design in python.
I'm working on a certain project and I can see that there is a certain amount of different types of errors that I have to handle often, which results in lots of places where there is a try...execept clause that repeats itself.

Now the question is, will it be more preferred to create one exception handler (a decorator) and decorate with it all those functions that have those repeating errors.

The trade off here is that if I create this exception handler decorator it will become quite a big of a class/function which will then make the person reading the code to try and understand another piece of complicated (maybe) logic to understand how the error is handled, where if I don't use the decorator, its pretty clear to the reader how is it handled.

Another option is to create multiple decorators for each of the types of the errors.

Or maybe just leave all those try...except clauses even though they are being repeated.

Any opinions on the matter and maybe other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Exception handling is a cross-cutting concern and should be handled as such. Usually, you would have a middleware that handle all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this is subjective, but I personally think it's better for exception handling code to be close to where the error is occurring, for the sake of readability and debugging ease. So:

> The trade off here is that if I create this exception handler decorator it will become quite a big of a class/function

I would recommend against the Mr. Fixit class. When an error occurs and the debugger drops you into the Mr. Fixit, you then have to walk back quite a bit before you can figure out why the error happened, and what needs to be fixed to make it go away. Likewise, an unfamiliar developer reading your code loses the ability to understand just one small snippet pertaining to a particular error, and now has to work through a large class. As an added issue, a lot of what's in the Mr. Fixit is irrelevant to the one error they're looking at, and the place where the error handling occurs is in an entirely different place. With decorators especially, I feel like you are sacrificing readability (especially for someone less familiar with decorators than you) while gaining not much.

If written with some care, try/catch blocks are not very performance intensive and do not clutter up code too much. I would suggest erring on the side of more try/catches, with every try/catch close to what it's handling, so that you can tell at a glance how errors are handled for any given piece of code (without having to go to a different file).

If you are repeating code a lot, you can either refactor by making the code inside the catch a method that can be repeatedly called, or by making the code inside the try its own method that does its error handling inside its body. When in doubt, keep it simple.

Also, I hate being a close/off-topic Nazi so I won't flag, but I do think this question is more suited to Programmers@SE (being an abstract philosophy/conceptual question) and you might get better responses on that site.

Comment: Usually, at the exception call site, you don't have the required context to recover. Is it safe to retry? Should the transaction be rolled-back? Those are policies that are applied higher in the call hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the `Programmes@SE` site, will post it there too.
About your answer, what about multiple small straight to the point decorators that let you easily know which error they are handling by an indicative name and simple logic?